# How to know current running topologies from storm command line client?

Tags: apache-storm

Is there any way to display all the current running Storm topologies from storm command line client?

Storm documentation doesn't say anything about this.

http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Command-line-client.html

Comment: you can use command:
$ bin/storm list

Comment: I guess writing 
"jps" without quotes   
will show you all the current java there you can see whether you topology is listed or not.

Comment: @anuj-pradhan In our server lists lot of Java processes are listed including Hadoop services, storm topologies and some other java applications... It is difficult to identify storm topologies alone..

Answer (score 4):

You can run

`$STORM_HOME/bin/storm list`

storm provides a web based UI for monitoring such informations.

However you can start writing your own `Thrift` client to connect to the broker and get various matrix based on your need. If you are from Java background or similar then it should be easy to write and execute from the prompt.